# html,head and body tags are being deleted after processing Javascript. So how to avoid such deletion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

With the help of the following code, I can add number of `colspan` according to number of `td` available within a table.The problem with is that, it is adding properly `colgroup`, but after processing, it is deleting some tags within that same page(`html,head,body tags`).

How can I avoid such deletion?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#btnApply').on('click', function() {

        var input = '<div>' + $('#input').text() + '</div>';
        var html = $('<div/>').html(input).contents();
        console.log(html.find('table'));
        var output = '';
        html.find('table').each(function() {

            var colCount = 0;
            $(this).find('tr:nth-child(1) td').each(function() { // Get the count of table columns

                if ($(this).attr('colspan')) { // if there is a <td colspan>
                    colCount += +$(this).attr('colspan');
                } else {
                    colCount++;
                }
                console.log($(this));
            });


            var colgroupList = '';
            for (i = 0; i < colCount; i++) { // Add a <colgroup></colgroup> for each <td>
                colgroupList += '<col width="50%"></col>';
                console.log(colgroupList);
            }
            console.log('<colgroup>' + colgroupList + '</colgroup>');

            $(this).find("tbody").prepend('<colgroup>' + colgroupList + '</colgroup>');

            output += '<table>' + $(this).html() + '</table>';

        });

        $('#output').html(output);
        $('#outputHTML').text(output);
        $('#outputArea').fadeIn(1000);

    });

});
```

So can anyone help me. You can view my **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/erxwao9h/10/)**.

Comment: How to replicate issue? What is expected behaviour? Are you saying that you cannot embeded on `html` inside the current one? If it is what you mean, then that's expected behaviour

Comment: @ A. Wolff  thanks for your response.
The issue is that, After adding colgroup, it is deleting <html> body and head tags.

you can try in my given fiddle, just add this following code in "Input box"
and then click on Apply Button.

you can we output in output box, and also in "output HTML box" you can view output (in this html,body,head tags are missing)

Comment: <html>   
     <head></head>
     <body>
<table border="1">    
<tr>
<th>Heading</th>
<td>col 1</td>
<td>col 2</td>
<td>col 3</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table border="1">    
<tr>
<th>Heading</th>
<td>col 1</td>
<td>col 2</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table border="1">    
<tr>
<th>Heading</th>
<td>col shri</td>
<td>col Heloo</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table border="1">    
<tr>
<th>Heading</th>
<td>col 1</td>
<td>col 2</td>
<td>col 3</td>
</tr>
</table>

    </body>
</html>

Comment: this is the same fiddle i wrote for someone's answer a month ago.

Comment: But you can only have one HTML, HEAD, BODY element in the context of document. You should use an iframe instead which has its own document context

Comment: oh ho, So you are that Guy.

@Sushil yup, I m her Friend. First of thanks for your help.
because of you, our project is going well.

Comment: oh great. its a small world after all. let me try and fix this for u.

Comment: What happend guys, No one is there or what? Can anyone help me & solve this issue please?

Comment: a little busy now. working on ur fiddle as well. will take some time.

Comment: ok ok... Thank you so much in Advance.....

Comment: @SnehaPatil can't you just use `output += '<html><head></head><body><table>' + $(this).html() + '</table></body></html>';`?? i told the same to your friend before as it is not possible in a div. you will have to use an iframe if you want the html as well

Comment: @Sushil can you suggest me how to use this with iFrame tags???

Comment: instead of creating a textarea, you can create an iframe and take input

Comment: @Sushil can you please send an example?

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to convert this code ,using iframe??????

Comment: instead of asking everybody what i'd suggest you is that you first try it. i gave you a hint already that you need to replace your textarea with iframe. now you can research how to add an editable iframe. its easy.. all you need to do is just try. try first and then let me know if you're facing any issues. if you keep asking people for giving you an example without you making any effort then nobody's going to do that.

Comment: To build on @Sushil's comment, you also wont ever learn if you expect others to do it for you.